# How to handle sharp edges on bevels

Tags: bevels

I am having some millwork done and the carpenters are reluctant to put knife edges on the bevels because they feel it would be fragile and the edges could get easily chipped in handling. They generally want to chamfer off any sharp 45-degree edges to an 1/8 or a 1/16th. The diagram below shows the basic situation:

[image]

Is there any way to handle such edges, or do they really need to be chamfered off to a 1/16th?

Comment: I've read that finishes are more likely to fail on sharp edges.

Comment: You can break the edge with sand paper, a few strokes down the length with fine paper 220 or so.

Comment: "they feel it would be fragile and the edges could get easily chipped in handling" should read "it would be fragile and the edges **would** get chipped in handling".

Answer (score 2):

To paraphrase pretty much *every* wood- and metal-worker on YouTube:

> **Always** chamfer your machined edges!

I'm not in the least surprised that people familiar with machining material have advised chamfered edges. It just looks, feels, and ages better.